# Translated pages load a white empty page on localised site

Tags: localization, url

I'm running Craft CMS 2.6.2949 on PHP 7.0.10.

I have set up 3 locales: nl_be, en and fr.

I have set the following config into general.php

```
    '.dev' => array(
    // ...
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'nl_be' => 'http://xxx.dev/',
        'en' => 'http://xxx.dev/en/',
        'fr' => 'http://xxx.dev/fr/'
    ),
```

I have set the section to translateable and set some fields to be translateable.

I have translated some entries.

When I open the entry in the main language (nl_be) the website load with the desired template and styling. http://xxx.dev/nieuws/2016/we-installeerden-net-dit

When I open the translated version 
http://xxx.dev/en/news/2016/we-just-installed-craft

I get a white, empty page. It seems like the template is not loaded.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance.

This is the first time I'm trying Craft and I really love it. Great work Pixel & Tonic!

Bart

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

I only copied the lines

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

// Tell Craft to serve the German content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'de');

// Do not edit below this line
// ...
```

from the example here: https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide to the index.php file in the localised folder.

I did not copy the $path lines from the original index.php file in the webroot. This way I got the white empty pages.

Thanks a lot for the help on Twitter. I'm on my way to finish my first site!

Comment: Nice job solving it Bart, and thanks for following up with an answer! Don't forget to accept it and collect some points.